# How can I switch from one user to another user inside a script?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, users, filenames

.The issue is my id 'aaa' can read only the file name and not the contents inside it when I log in with my id "aaa". So to read the contents I have to switch to another user "bbb" which is having permission to read the contents in that file by using the below command:

```
pbrun /bin/su - bbb
```

to automate the above manual work I have written a script to check everyday whether a job file posted or not. How to use the above  command inside my script which is executed under my id 'aaa'?

```
#!/bin/ksh
fname = /home/job/file1.log
#this is the path where file1.log will be posted everyday
var =$(grep 'job finished successfully ' $fname )
# my id 'aaa' is not having  privilege to read file contents only
# id 'bbb' is having the privilege so when i execute the script with
# my id the above line wont work .

if [ -e "$fname"] && [! -z "var"]

    echo " $fname has posted successfully " >>wa.txt
    mail -s "File  ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt
else
    echo " $fname has not posted " >>wa.txt
    mail -s "File  ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt   
fi

rm wa.txt 2>ni.txt
```

i tried below option  but it did not work .

```
#!/bin/ksh
pbrun /bin/su - bbb
```

rest of the script ....

Comment: pbrun and su do the same thing. Both change the effective user, so just use pbrun directly. "pbrun -u bbb command" to run the commands which need to be run as user bbb.

Comment: if you have the right change your user id to bbb, according to the powerbroker role definitions, `var =$(pbrun -u bbb "grep 'job finished successfully '" $fname )` should work (please test how the quotation marks work under pbrun. I haven't used it for more than 10 years now and forgot the syntax)

Comment: Is an internal ssh an option?

Comment: yes first i login with my id 'aaa' then i  have to ssh "server name " then i have to execute the above script .

Comment: I such cases better to add users in same group and add group read/write permissions to the logfile

Comment: @Mr.V.K. the challenge is i cant add/remove/create group with permission or change the logfile permission .

Comment: what about just changing the line `mail -s "File  ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt` to `su bbb -c 'mail -s "File  ALERT" abc@aaa.com <wa.txt'` ? This make not the whole of your script run as `bbb` but only the mail command. You would of cause still need to enter the password... Another (better) way would be to become bbb and create a cronjob that does this work for you.

Comment: @max :  thanks 
 var =$(grep 'job finished successfully ' $fname ) 
only id 'bbb' has permission to grep the contents of file  so the above line wont excute with my id 'aaa' and  there wont be any change by adding su bb -c mail  -s "file alert"

Comment: @star: you are right. i didn't see this line. well, what about the cron job? otherwise my best bet would be to write two scripts. the first one calling the second as bbb, the second doing just what your script does now. so the runner-script would do something like this: `su -c ./your-script.ksh bbb`. you must of cause make sure, that user bbb may create/append to wa.txt.... best way would still be a cron job for bbb. this would make entering the password unnessesary.

Comment: @max i will try this option and let u know thanks for the information